# Configure SSRS with SharePoint 2010 Complete Server without AD

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth, reporting-services, configuration, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to configure SharePoint 2010 in claims mode on an all-in-one development box with SQL Server 2012?  If so, how?

To be clear, this is a development box that is NOT attached to a domain.  It is running using all local accounts, but not as a SharePoint stand alone deployment as enterprise features are in use.  All other services (search, etc) are configured and functional.  SSRS reports are generating the dreaded "Cannot convert claims identity to windows token" exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this wont work.  While reporting services is claims aware, you still need Claims to Windows Token Service (C2TWS) to access the data source - even if it's all local.  You can't use local accounts with C2TWS because it will do a query to resolve the UPN to match to a claim.

Comment: Testing thus far has borne out you suspicion.